# Grouping array with consecutive keys

Tags: php

I've an array like this -

```
 Array
(
    [16] => 424
    [17] => 404
    [18] => 416
    [21] => 404
    [22] => 456
    [23] => 879
    [28] => 456
    [29] => 456
    [32] => 123
    [35] => 465
)
```

The output of this array would be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
           (   ['start'] => 16
               ['stop'] => 19
           )
    [1] => Array
           (   ['start'] => 21
               ['stop'] => 24
           )
    [2] => Array
           (
               ['start'] => 28
               ['stop'] => 30
           )
    [3] => Array
           (
               ['start'] => 32
               ['stop'] => 33
           )
    [4] => Array
           (
               ['start'] => 35
               ['stop'] => 36
           )
)
```

I don't really need the values. Just grouping the keys.

The 'start' value should be the 'start' value itself. Whereas, the 'stop' value should be a consecutive integer.

And if consecutive integer doesn't exist for a particular key(like for [32] and [35]), 'stop' should be the integer+1 (same as above) .

Thank you all for help.

Comment: i dont know if your example is really consistent.  for lonely integers shouldnt the stop/start be equal?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a point. Question updated, please recheck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
reset($arr);
$lastKey = key($arr);
$ansIndex = -1;
$ans = array();

foreach ($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    if ($k != $lastKey + 1)
    {
         $ansIndex++;
         $ans[$ansIndex]['start'] = $k; 
    }

    $ans[$ansIndex]['stop']  = $k+1;
    $lastKey = $k;
}
```

EDIT - changed $k to $k+1 for the `stop` indexes to reflect change in your question
EDIT - noticed i had a line of code within both `if` and `else`.  taking it out of conditional since it runs regardless.

Comment: This worked. Just a note, why is $lastKey set to -1? Putting `reset($arr)` and setting `$lastKey` to `key($arr)` did the trick. Please update your answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: ok sounds good. i just picked `-1` as something that could be relied upon to be different

Comment: what changes do you want?  where is this reset?  cant be within the loop.  `key($arr) === $k` at all times, so for clarity sake i wouldnt change one unless you are going to change every time

Comment: o nevermind, i see you are just talking about initialization.  good idea i like that better than me pulling `-1` out of my ass